# Where do I find dataset for rectangular patch antenna?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-selection, linear-regression

I am doing a project in my college, and for that I need a dataset containing the length, width , height along with return loss for different frequency of operation of the rectangular patch antenna. This is basically to train an ML model that, once trained, if we give the frequency of operation, it would tell the dimensions of the patch antenna for optimum return loss. Do you know where I can find such a dataset. I searched in many places, including Kaggle, but I couldn't find any.